# MS Lightswitch error "Resource not found for the segment" Entity with missing letter

Tags: http, https, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

In Microsoft LightSwitch I created an application that works on my desktop and sandbox, but when deploying to production I get "Resource not found for the segment 'lients' ", but it's supposed to be 'Clients' whenever it is updating or deleting.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Just putting it out here for anyone that needs it. The issue which can be found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fff9b50d-800c-4154-b432-2229239ca472/lightswitch-html-client-generates-wrong-request-for-entity-deletion?forum=lightswitch), was that there is a bug in the code. When the site is changed from HTTP to HTTPS outside of LightSwitch, it retains the original URL and your entity name is reduced by one character.

The workaround is to go to file 'Scripts\msls-2.0.0.js' at line 7026 which looks like this:

> request.requestUri = metadata.uri.substr(
>   dataServiceDetails._serviceUri.length + 1);

and change this line to:

> var protocol = /^(https|http)/i;
>
> request.requestUri = metadata.uri.replace(protocol,
>   '').substr(dataServiceDetails._serviceUri.replace(protocol, '').length
>   + 1);